# lseek/write suddenly returns -1 with errno = 9 (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: c, file-io, handle, seek

My application uses `lseek()` to seek the desired position to write data.
The file is successfully opened using `open()` and my application was able to use `lseek()` and `write()` lots of times.

At a given time, for some users and not easily reproducable, `lseek()` returns -1 with an `errno` of 9. File is not closed before this and the filehandle (int) isn't reset.

After this, another file is created; `open()` is okay again and `lseek()` and `write()` works again.

To make it even worse, this user tried the complete sequence again and all was well.

So my question is, can the OS close the file handle for me for some reason?
What could cause this? A file indexer or file scanner of some sort?

What is the best way to solve this; is this pseudo code the best solution?
(never mind the code layout, will create functions for it)

```
int fd=open(...);
if (fd>-1) {
  long result = lseek(fd,....);
  if (result == -1 && errno==9) {
      close(fd..); //make sure we try to close nicely
      fd=open(...);

      result = lseek(fd,....);
  }
}
```

Anybody experience with something similar?

Summary: file seek and write works okay for a given fd and suddenly gives back errno=9 without a reason.

Comment: My code won't compile if I try to open(...); Odd.

Comment: If lseek() fails with EBADF, you can be pretty sure that close() on the same file descriptor will also fail with EBADF.  And since you don't check your re-open or re-seek calls, anything could be happening.

Comment: @ Ger Teunis: If what you post is pseudocode, mark it as such, so people won't complain (as Tim did) or simply tell you "works for me".

Avoid posting pseudocode if at all possible - the process of finding the smallest possible piece of code to reproduce the problem is a valuable part of the art of debugging.

Quite often the problem is not where you think it is, and the pseudocode you post doesn't even contain the core of the problem (in this case, the file residing on a network mount).

Comment: I missed the pseudo code part. I apologize for that, my fault, and again my fault for using strong language without double-checking.

Comment: upvote for standing to wise asses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what type of setup you have, but the following scenario, could I think produce such an effect (or else one similar to it).  I have not tested this to verify, so please take it with a grain of salt.

If the file/device you are opening implemented as a server application (eg NFS), consider what could happen if the server application goes down / restarts / reboots.  The file descriptor though originally valid at the client end might no longer map to a valid file handle at the server end.  This can conceivably lead to a sequence of events wherein the client will get EBADF.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right here. All file handles where okay. No closing of file handles. There wasn't a problem in my code just osx marking the fh invalid. Reoping the file also returned the fd id.
Funny stuff.

Answer (score 7):

> So my question is, can the OS close the file handle for me for some reason? What could cause > this? A file indexer or file scanner of some sort?

No, this will not happen.

> What is the best way to solve this; is
>   this pseudo code the best solution?
>   (never mind the code layout, will
>   create functions for it)

No, the best way is to find the bug and fix it.

> Anybody experience with something similar?

I've seen fds getting messed up many times, resulting in EBADF in the some of the cases,
and blowing up spectacularly in others, it's been:

- buffer overflows - overflowing something and writing a nonsense value into a 'int fd;' variable.
- silly bugs that happen because some corner case someone did
  `if(fd = foo[i].fd)` when they meant `if(fd == foo[i].fd)`
- Raceconditions between threads, some thread closes the wrong file descriptor that some other thread wants to use.

If you can find a way to reproduce this problem, run your program under 'strace', so you can see whats going on.

Comment: I do agree about finding the bug. I'll do some more code review but I will check what happens if i.e. a network drive is disconnected. Perhaps this will cause an Bad File descriptor?

Comment: After close inspection the fd doesn't change at all and only one thread is doing the disk IO (all file handling).

I may assume if I do not close the fd, the fd remains the same I should not get the errno and -1 result right? It really does.

Comment: While some particular OS, utilizing some particular filesystem/network IO could have some corner case bug that causes this to happen is entierly possible, it'd just be guesswork. a strace of all the threads  when this does happen would be very helpful though

Comment: After a lot more logging and debugging it was not an error in my code. The fh's never change and it doesn't close them. The file handles are controlled ouside of my program scope (open and write) so it's not a memory issue as well.You are right here. All file handles where okay. No closing of file handles. There wasn't a problem in my code just osx marking the fh invalid. Reoping the file also returned the Same fd id.
Funny stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The OS shall not close file handles randomly (I am assuming a Unix-like system). If your file handle is closed, then there is something wrong with your code, most probably elsewhere (thanks to the C language and the Unix API, this can be really anywhere in the code, and may be due to, e.g., a slight buffer overflow in some piece of code which really looks like to be unrelated).

Your pseudo-code is the worst solution, since it will give you the impression of having fixed the problem, while the bug still lurks.

I suggest that you add debug prints (i.e. `printf()` calls) wherever you open and close a file or socket. Also, try [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

(I just had yesterday a spooky off-by-1 buffer overflow, which damaged the least significant byte of a temporary slot generated by the compiler to save a CPU register; the indirect effect was that a structure in another function appeared to be shifted by a few bytes. It took me quite some time to understand what was going on, including some thorough reading of Mips assembly code).

Comment: Was expecting this reaction, which is the most obvious one of course.

No to be cocky, but I am almost sure there isn't a memory leak.
The file handle id remains the same (checked) and the lseek and write just before it worked fine. There is nothing dynamic (memory wise) going on between write operations.
All file IO code is being logged (NSlog) and all is going okay, until suddenly in some situations (not reproducible second time) the -1 occurs with errno=9.

You have to agree that whenever the fd doesn't change it is most unlikely the errno=9 would appear right? For some reason it does.

Comment: @Thomas: +1 I couldn't agree more. Bugs should be fixed, not hidden. @Ger, how can you be sure you don't have stack or heap corruption?  This sounds like a sinister bug which needs fixing

Comment: Sure I do agree, better find the cause. But at first sight it seems the cause was outside my scope. It still seems that way because there is no way the current fd is being overwritten with another value.

Comment: Some made a suggestion what might happen if the (network) drive suddenly gets disconnected. Will have look into that.

Answer (score 0):

No, the OS should not close file handles just like that, and other applications (file scanners etc.) should not be *able* to do it.

Do not work around the problem, find it's source. If you don't know what the reason for your problem was, you will never know if your workaround actually *does* work.

1. **Check your assumptions.** Is `errno` set to 0 before the call? Is fd really valid at the point the call is being made? (I know you said it is, but did you **check** it?)
2. What is the output of `puts( strerror( 9 ) );` on your platform?

Comment: errno is 0 before and result of lseek suddenly is -1.
fd is REALLY REALLY open because the writes do work before in the same iteration.

Comment: Well then, go on checking your assumptions. You know your code better than me. Printing the value of fd before each call would be my next move.

Comment: Good idea and also a suggestion what happens when a (network) drive gets disconnected for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar error, however the root cause was completely different. According to the [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) the `EBADF` may appear when for example when "I/O on a descriptor [...] has been closed [...]". And I encapsulated everything in a beautiful class that did close the descriptor on move. Please look at the fixed fragment of the code, so you'll got the reason:

```
class File
{
    private:

        FILE *file = nullptr;

    public:

        File() noexcept = default;

        File(File &&file) noexcept
        {
            std::swap(file.file, this->file);
        }

        File(const File &) noexcept = delete;
        File &operator=(File &&) noexcept = delete;
        File &operator=(const File &) noexcept = delete;

        ~File() noexcept
        {
            close();
        }

        void close() noexcept
        {
            if (file) {
                fclose(file);
                file = nullptr;
            }
        }

        // ...
};
```