# Failed "write" unix system call

Tags: c, unix

The third line below returns -1. What should I do to debug?

```
void *zeroed_block = calloc(512, 1);
lseek(3, sectorNum * 512, SEEK_SET);
return write(fd, zeroed_block, 512); /* This line returns -1 */
```

When I print the error caused by write (using perror) The reason is "Bad file descriptor"

Here's the code where I open the file descriptor:

```
char *diskpath = argv[optind]; – Rose Perrone 1 min ago edit 
int fd = diskimg_open(diskpath, (removeFlag == NULL)); 

int
diskimg_open (char *pathname, int readOnly)
{
  return open(pathname, readOnly ? O_RDONLY : O_RDWR);
}
```

The opening the file descriptor works relialbly every other time I use it, outside these three lines of code.

I'm on Mac OS, so here's the output of `dtruss`, as requested:

```
SYSCALL(args)        = return
open(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)        = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF63557420, 0x0)        = 0 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x32, 0x7FFF635576A0)         = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
stat64("/Users/rdp/Documents/School/110/readfiles/code\0", 0x7FFF63557390, 0x0) = 0 0
issetugid(0x7FFF63593530, 0x7FFF63557BFA, 0x7FFF63593530)        = 0 0
csops(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF6355767C)      = 0 0
shared_region_check_np(0x7FFF635555C8, 0x2, 0x55)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63556790, 0x7FFF63557680 = 0 0
__sysctl(0x7FFF6355702C, 0x2, 0x7FFF63557018)        = 0 0
bsdthread_register(0x7FFF911A6B68, 0x7FFF911A6B78, 0x2000)       = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x7FFF911A6B68, 0x7FFF911A6B78, 0x0)       = 444904 0
mmap(0x0, 0x2000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x4)       = 0x3961000 0
mprotect(0x103961000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
mmap(0x0, 0x17000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x6)      = 0x3969000 0
mprotect(0x103969000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10397F000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mmap(0x0, 0x17000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x6)      = 0x3980000 0
mprotect(0x103980000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x103996000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mmap(0x0, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x6)       = 0x3963000 0
mprotect(0x103963000, 0x1000, 0x1)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x103961000, 0x88, 0x3)         = 0 0
mmap(0x7FA408400000, 0x200000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x7000000, 0x6)      = 0x3997000 0
munmap(0x103997000, 0x69000)         = 0 0
munmap(0x103B00000, 0x97000)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x103961000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
getpid(0x7FFF63556E64, 0x3, 0x1)         = 58942 0
__mac_syscall(0x7FFF8F05E7FE, 0x2, 0x7FFF63556EB0)       = 0 0
stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFF63556F18, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
audit_session_self(0x7FFF63556C68, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC, 0x4)      = 5123 0
geteuid(0x7FFF63556C68, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC, 0x0)         = 0 0
getegid(0x7FFF63556C68, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC, 0x0)         = 0 0
getaudit_addr(0x7FFF63556EB0, 0x30, 0x0)         = 0 0
csops(0xE63E, 0x7, 0x7FFF63556AE0)       = 0 0
mmap(0x0, 0x2000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x14)      = 0x3997000 0
mprotect(0x103997000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
mmap(0x0, 0x17000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x6)      = 0x3999000 0
mprotect(0x103999000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x1039AF000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mmap(0x0, 0x17000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x6)      = 0x39B0000 0
mprotect(0x1039B0000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x1039C6000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x103963000, 0x1000, 0x3)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x103963000, 0x1000, 0x1)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x103997000, 0x88, 0x3)         = 0 0
mmap(0x7FA3F8400000, 0x200000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x7000000, 0x7)      = 0xF8400000 0
munmap(0x7FA3F8500000, 0x100000)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x103997000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
open("../3testdisks/basicDiskImage\0", 0x0, 0x1)         = 3 0
lseek(0x3, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
read(0x3, "\a\001\0", 0x200)         = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x200, 0x0)       = 512 0
read(0x3, "\020\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x0, 0x2)         = 10240000 0
getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFF63556F10, 0x10395B430)       = 0 0
fstat64(0x1, 0x7FFF63556E78, 0x7FFF63556F3C)         = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFF63556F14)       = 0 0
mmap(0x7FA3F8400000, 0x1000000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x2000000, 0x6)         = 0xF8500000 0
munmap(0x7FA3F8500000, 0x300000)         = 0 0
munmap(0x7FA3F9000000, 0x500000)         = 0 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "Disk -t is 10240000 bytes (10000 KB)\n\0", 0x25)        = 37 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "Superblock s_isize 16\n\0", 0x16)       = 22 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "Superblock s_fsize 20000\n\0", 0x19)        = 25 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "Superblock s_nfree 89\n\0", 0x16)       = 22 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "Superblock s_ninode 0\n\0", 0x16)       = 22 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AA800, 0x0)        = 8038400 0
read(0x3, "_<`<c<f<i<l<o<r<u<a<d<g<j<m<p<s<v<b<e<h<k<n<q<t<w<x<{<~<\201<\204<\207<\212<\215<y<|<\177<\202<\205<\210<\213<\216<z<}<\200<\203<\206<\211<\214<\217<\220<\223<\226<\231<\234<\237<\242<\245<\221<\224<\227<\232<\235<\240<\243<\246<\222<\225<\230<\233<\236<\241<\244<\247<\250<\253<\256<\261<\264<\267<\272<\275<\251<\254<\257<\262<\265<\270<\273<\276<\252<\255<\260<\263<\266<\271<\274<\277<\300<\303<\306<\311<\314<\317<\322<\325<\301<\304<\307<\312<\315<\320<\323<\326<\302<\305<\310<\313<\316<\321<\324<\327<\330<\333<\336<\341<\344<\347<\352<", 0x200)         = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x78BE00, 0x0)        = 7912960 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1789 (ID 118: syscall::write:return): out of scratch space in action #12 at DIF offset 44
writev_nocancel(0x2, 0x7FFF635570E8, 0x4)        = 31 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "Uh oh. inode_zero_contents returns -1.\0", 0x26)        = 38 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1789 (ID 118: syscall::write:return): out of scratch space in action #12 at DIF offset 44
writev_nocancel(0x2, 0x7FFF63556E48, 0x4)        = 31 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "Uh oh. inode_zero_contents returns -1.\0", 0x26)        = 38 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7ACC00, 0x0)        = 8047616 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x400, 0x0)       = 1024 0
read(0x3, "\377\301\004\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
lseek(0x3, 0x7AC600, 0x0)        = 8046080 0
read(0x3, "\001\0", 0x200)       = 512 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "The file was not removed. We can still find it . That's a problem. The file was located at /foo/XXX\n\0", 0x64)         = 100 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE8)         = 3 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFF63557518)       = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib\0", 0x7FFF635565C0, 0x7FFF63557440)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib\0", 0x7FFF635564D0, 0x7FFF63557350)         = 0 0
open("/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\312\376\272\276\0", 0x1000, 0x0)        = 4096 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x1000)       = 4096 0
mmap(0x103964000, 0x2000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x100001F)         = 0x3964000 0
mmap(0x103966000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x100001F)         = 0x3966000 0
mmap(0x103967000, 0x1F40, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x100001F)         = 0x3967000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib\0", 0x7FFF635565A0, 0x7FFF63557420)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib\0", 0x7FFF635565A0, 0x7FFF63557420)   = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib\0", 0x7FFF635565A0, 0x7FFF63557420)       = 0 0
stat64("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent\0", 0x7FFF635563A0, 0x7FFF63557220)         = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib\0", 0x7FFF635563A0, 0x7FFF63557220)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)   = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40 = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)     = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)  = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)  = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)   = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40) = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40) = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)    = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40 = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)     = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)  = 0 0
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib\0", 0x7FFF63555FC0, 0x7FFF63556E40)     = 0 0
getpid(0x7FFF63557498, 0x103960004, 0xEA60)      = 58942 0
```

Comment: Yes, I printed fd in gdb

Comment: How did you get `fd`, will say: please show us the call to `open()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you asked ***What should I do to debug?***

```
if(write(fd, zeroed_block,512) < 0){
  perror("Reason : ");
}
```

to get a better error message

Comment: (gdb) Reason : : Bad file descriptor                                                                                     (gdb) p fd                                                                                                            $1 = 3

Comment: I changed fd to 3, and I got the same Reason.

Comment: char *diskpath = argv[optind];

Comment: int fd = diskimg_open(diskpath, (removeFlag == NULL)); diskimg_open calls open(diskpath, readOnly ? O_RDONLY : O_RDWR);

Comment: @RosePerrone don't put code in comments.. Please edit your original questions and put it there..

Comment: Might be interesting.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544898/lseek-write-suddenly-returns-1-with-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to debug?

You can use `strace` to get error messages caused by system calls. Since error is "Bad file descriptor", you can look in strace log when it was created and what happened with it before you tried to write.

Comment: I'm actually on Mac OS, so I used `dtruss`, and posted the output in my question.

Comment: @Rose Perrone: Probably you are opening `basicDiskImage` for reading only. Unfortunately `dtruss` does not show the values of `open` flags in human readable form.